# Blob Object returns prefetchdata instead of bytecode via blob.getBytes()

Tags: java, sql, arrays, oracle, blob

I am retrieving a BLOB from an Oracle (SQL) DB within a batch tasklet.
To get the underlying File as Byte[] I was using something like this:

```
byte[] blobAsByte = blob.getBytes(1l, (int) blob.length());
```

And passing this, with the appropriate mime-type into a datasource.

The problem is, the returned length as well as the returned bytes represent the content of the "prefetchdata", not the actual data is what i found, while debugging and looking at what the blob object contains.

Can you tell me, how I can retrieve the actual data?

And does this structure represent a proper blob object in java:

```
Name: blob
Value: $Proxy377
    Name: h
    Value: SerializableBlobProxy
        Name: blob
        Delegate: DelegatingBlob
            Name: delegate
            Value: BLOB
                Name: OjiOracleBlob
                    Name: data
                    Value:[0]...[113]
                    Name: prefetchData
                    Value:[0]...[5]
```

Answer (score 0):

To read from a BLOB, use the `getBinaryStream()` method of an oracle.sql.BLOB object to retrieve the entire BLOB as an input stream. This returns a `java.io.InputStream` object.
As with any `InputStream` object, use one of the overloaded `read()` methods to read the LOB data, and use the `close()` method when you finish. (Or from Java 9 use `readAllBytes()`)

In your case the following should work:

```
byte[] blobAsByte = blob.getBinaryStream().readAllBytes();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But the problem remains the same. The 6 Values of prefetchData are read and not the 114 actual ones.

Comment: What does the code look like that populates the blob value? I am looking for OracleResultSet.getBLOB(int columnIndex)

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the prefetching of BLOB data entirely with

```
oracle.jdbc.defaultLobPrefetchSize=-1
```

or set it to the desired size in bytes, example for 4k

```
oracle.jdbc.defaultLobPrefetchSize=4000
```